# Rolling 31 day average including previous 31 days from BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've created a query that returns a counts the number of rows (records) for the last 31 days (based on a `timestamp` field) and include the previous 31 days before that period as well, eg. produce a query that returns both. I now have the following query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY datetime DESC RANGE BETWEEN 2678400000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS rolling_avg_31_days,
  COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY datetime DESC RANGE BETWEEN 5356800000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS rolling_avg_62_days
FROM `p`
ORDER BY rolling_avg_31_days DESC LIMIT 1
```

And it returns some data, but not really the data I was hoping for:

```
rolling_avg_31_days | rolling_avg_62_days   
          8,422,783 | 9,790,304
```

If I query the same table with (rolling 62 days):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM `p`
WHERE datetime > UNIX_MILLIS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-5356800000 AND datetime < UNIX_MILLIS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-2678400000'
```

I get a value of `6,192,920`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the first query is correct and gives you rolling counts (31 and 62 days) **based on the timestamp field** - also, because of `order by .. desc` and `limit 1` you are getting the most row that has biggest `rolling_avg_31_days` which is not necessarily row for the most recent () datetime

The second query just produces count of rows between 62 and 31 days based on the current timestamp - which is as explain above is not what first query produces - thus the discrepancy

To further `troubleshoot` or to try to understand difference - change `ORDER BY rolling_avg_31_days DESC LIMIT 1` to `ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1` and also add `datetime` to select statement so you can see if it belong to current date or close to current statement so results are comparable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going with the above, I've decided to change the query to be a bit simpler:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(wasabi_user_id)) FROM `p` WHERE datetime > UNIX_MILLIS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-5356800000 AND datetime < UNIX_MILLIS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-2678400000) as _62days,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(wasabi_user_id)) FROM `p` WHERE datetime > UNIX_MILLIS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-2678400000) AS _31days
FROM `mycujoo_kafka_public.v_web_event_pageviews` LIMIT 1
```

Thanks @Mikhail for the help though!

Comment: Consider voting up my answer if it helped, which looks like it did!